# Can an instructor with an Instrument Airplane Instructor rating instruct for PPL?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, ppl, instrument-rating, ground-instructor

I'm graduating from college this May, and as a graduation gift, I'm planning on getting my FAA PPL. I'm wondering if my father (with the FAA ratings below) could be my instructor for the 20 hours of dual flight. If not, what specific rating would he need to obtain to be able to be my instructor?

AIRLINE TRANSPORT PILOT:

- AIRPLANE SINGLE ENGINE LAND

COMMERCIAL PRIVILEGES:

- AIRPLANE SINGLE-ENGINE SEA
- AIRPLANE MULTIENGINE LAND

FLIGHT INSTRUCTOR:

- INSTRUMENT AIRPLANE

Answer (score 1):

Your dad cannot provide any flight training without a category and class on his flight instructor certificate.  He will need to take a practical test to add the category and class onto his flight instructor certificate for the airplane you want training in.

> [§ 61.195 Flight instructor limitations and qualifications.](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-H)
>
> A person who holds a flight instructor certificate is subject to the following limitations:
>
> > (a) Hours of training.  In any 24-consecutive-hour period, a flight instructor may not conduct more than 8 hours of flight training.
>
> > (b) Aircraft ratings.  Except as provided in paragraph (c) of this section, a flight instructor may not conduct flight training in any aircraft unless the flight instructor:
> >
> > > (1) **Holds a flight instructor certificate with the applicable category and class rating;**
> > >
> > > (2) Holds a pilot certificate with the applicable category and class rating; and
> > >
> > > (3) Meets the requirements of paragraph (e) of this section, if applicable.

It is also true for training in a simulator, FSTD or other such devices.

[Beard Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2012/Beard_2012_Legal_Interpretation.pdf)

Comment: The rules changed in 2012.  Hence, the question on the ability to use the sim with only a CFII.  Before that date, you could instruct instruments in the category you had the instrument privileges for.

Comment: The Beard Interpretation is fairly clear, but this then means anyone with a CFI-Instrument Airplane rating only cannot give any instruction at all.  (sim or aircraft)

Comment: Not in an aircraft.  They can teach instrument ground schools through for the instrument category they hold.